# Uninstalling canopy express

Tags: canopy

I have installed canopy express and want to get rid of it. I do this through unistall manager from Windows 7. While it completes unnstallating canopy is still in my start up and while i am trying to install python(x,y) it says that python is already installed, possibly because of canopy.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see this article in the Enthought knowledge base:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-Canopy